Load Model in container Azure App Services
I am making an api with a container in Azure App Service, I have a machine learning model in .h5 format, I am leaving the model in the internal storage of the container, but when I open the model with the load_model() function Keras, it loads and gives an error, the error is not related to the internet, I suppose it is the loading time. Any idea what I can do to solve it?
I've tried everything but I can't get the error

You need to implement proper error handling and log the error or return it through your API response. Without it, I don't think many people will be able to help.

The error occurs in this line and confirms it
model = load_model(path_model)
I checked beforehand that path_model exists as a file, and the local model works, but now I'm going to investigate whether I can investigate adding error handling.

Try: \n model = load_model(path_model) \n except Exception as e: \n printf(f"An error occurred: {e}

Well, I put that line in the call to the endpoint, since otherwise the application would never load. So the API loads and that endpoint gives this error:
Details
502
Undocumented
Error: Bad Gateway
Response headers
content-length: 0
date: Thu,25 Apr 2024 12:37:22 GMT

After trying again I get this error
Error: Gateway Timeout
Response body
Download
504.0 GatewayTimeout

Is path_model the path to a file local to the API? Where are you seeing this error? Is it from your API? Or is it from the client calling the API? If its your calling client then maybe load_model is taking a long time.

The model is in the local storage of the container, if I put the line load_model, as a global variable, the API is never started from Azure App Service, if I put it on the endpoint, the API is executed but on the endpoint it gives that error what I gave you, even with the try-except block

It's most likely the container is running out of memory. Is your container on an app service plan? Have you tried scaling up that plan?

The plan is an Azure promotion for the company, even so in these days I would have to contact the Azure team to see if that is the problem and I should fix it by increasing the storage.

If you have a reference machine where the model loads successfully, note the specifications and consult your Azure team on provisioning comparable resources. You should compare storage, memory, and CPU cores.
